# forEach для изменения регистра второй буквы

Tags: javascript, foreach

Как используя метод forEach, можно сделать заглавной вторую букву, а остальные в нижнем регистре.

```
const names = ['vladiMir', 'MaRk', 'LoGAn', 'VicTOr', 'mAks', 'KaTe', 'AlEx'];


names.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
   arr[i] = item[0].toLowerCase() + item.slice(1, 2).toLocaleUpperCase() + item.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(names);
```

Comment: непонятно какой результат ты в итоге ожидаешь

Comment: Чтоб каждая вторая буква была заглавной

Comment: @salco2012, добавьте пример, ничего не ясно.

Comment: @salco2012, приведи в вопросе результат для твоего массива names. Сейчас ты в одном месте пишешь просто про вторую букву, в другом про каждую вторую. Так же непонятно, чем не устраивает код, который приведен в вопросе.

Comment: @mymedia, titleCase это когда первая буква большая, в вопросе о другом речь

Comment: У вас есть два параметра  `item и i` когда вы посмотрите в документацию и выясните, что они означают, то все сделаете и настроение у вас улучшится. Ключевое слово: документация, или по-русски `rtfm`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const names = ['vladiMir', 'MaRk', 'LoGAn', 'VicTOr', 'mAks', 'KaTe', 'AlEx'];

names.forEach((name, index, array) => {
    name = name.toLocaleLowerCase();
    array[index] = name[0] + name.substr(1, 1).toLocaleUpperCase() + name.substr(2);
});

console.log(names);
```